# How to post form inside load() div

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have form with $_POST type from second page,on first page i've loaded the form with this code :

```
<div class="option_dialog" id="search">
<div class="close_option">Search <img onclick="search()" style="float:right;height:20px" src="img/close.png">
</div>
<div id="search_content" style="overflow:scroll;max-height:400px">
  <script>
  $('#first_page_div').load('second_page.php #second_page_form');
  </script>
</div>
</div>
```

When the function search() called using onclick the above code will excuted and load the form from second page...then i submit the form using this code :

```
$(function () {
    $('#form_id').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'second_page.php',
      data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
      success: function () {
        $('#first_page_search_result').load('second_page.php #searched_result');
        search_result();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

When form submited via ajax on first page,the second page should process his/her request and return the searched result on first page and execute search_result() which is another hidden div will be shown after returned result.
please tell me how to make this work?regards

Comment: Why are you loading search.php? Where is the actual form?

Comment: @APAD1 sorry , search is the second page,which the form exist there,forgot to edite this